# Magento2: How to use flat table instead of EAV?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have a Magento 2 project, in which the customer will have only a very few attributes. So instead of EAV, I want to use Flat Tables (i.e I want all the attributes to be columns).

Customer Address will remain out of this and will work as is (default implementation).

Has anyone done anything like this in Magento 1 or 2 ?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/ + I'd highly question the reason why I want something like this

Comment: Magento always uses the EAV system for the *real* data - but you can [configure it to use flat tables](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-enable-flat-catalog-magento-2.html) as well... the frontend will then read the data from the flat tables. I think that's about the closest you'll be able to get.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of magento 2, you should add those columns to the customer_entity_table
You can add them by setup/patch or db_schema.xml use varchar as type